# Changing Destructor order

Tags: c++

I need in destruction of a class that first the destructor of members are called before the class itself. 
I know the destruction order are normally in the reverse order. But I nedd this in special case.

```
// PortA
class PortA
{
public:
    PortA()     { cout << " PortA\n"; }
    ~PortA()    { cout << " ~PortA\n"; }
};

// PortB
class PortB
{
public:
    PortB()     { cout << " PortB\n"; }
    ~PortB()    { cout << " ~PortB\n"; }
};


class Card
{
public:
    Card()      { cout << "card\n"; }
    ~Card()     { cout << "~card\n"; }


    PortA mPA;
    PortB mPB;
};
```

That produces :

```
 PortA
 PortB
card
~card
 ~PortB
 ~PortA
```

But I need in this case:

```
card
 PortA
 PortB
 ~PortB
 ~PortA
~card
```

Closse first the port before the card itself.

Comment: So create a container class that has members in that order.

Comment: You may use smart pointer e.g. `std::unique_ptr<>` and create `PortA` and `PortB` manually inside `Card` constructor and free using `.reset()` in destructor

Comment: Two questions.   Firstly, why do you rely on such an order of destruction that differs from order of construction?   Second, if the construction of `PortB` fails (e.g. throws an exception) - after `PortA` is constructed - do you expect `PortA` to be destructed?

Comment: @BoBTFish  is this the same technique as CardWrapper described below as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider manipulate them explicitly, for example:

```
class Card
{
public:
    Card()      
    {
        cout << "card\n";
        mPA = new PortA;
        mPB = new PortB;
    }

    ~Card()     
    {
        delete mPB;
        delete mPA;
        cout << "~card\n"; 
    }


    PortA *mPA = nullptr;
    PortB *mPB = nullptr;
};
```

Now if you write something like this:

```
{
    Card c;
}
```

you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a base class to `Card`:

```
class BaseCard {
public:
    BaseCard()  { std::cout << "basecard\n"; }
    ~BaseCard() { std::cout << "~basecard\n"; }
};

class Card : BaseCard
{
public:
    Card()      { std::cout << "card\n"; }
    ~Card()     { std::cout << "~card\n"; }


    PortA mPA;
    PortB mPB;
};
```

Has `BaseCard`'s constructor and destructor called when you need:

```
basecard
 PortA
 PortB
card
~card
 ~PortB
 ~PortA
~basecard
```

---

Alternatively, you could lift `PortA` and `PortB` out of `Card` and lay all three as members inside a wrapper:

```
class CardWrapper {
    Card card;
    PortA mPA;
    PortB mPB;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is a robust and explicit destruction.

I would define a `destroy()` method in the ports, and then would call them from within the destructor of card.